# Add packages (application) to my ubuntu based distro

Tags: 14.04

I am creating an ubuntu based distro, and I want to add an ubuntu app to it so it is available for use straight away when the user installs the iso. I was just wondering how to go about this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: have you not tried `cubic` https://launchpad.net/~cubic-wizard/+archive/ubuntu/release

Comment: Is the `14.04` tag intended? That release reaches EOL for community support next month....